# Convert a "hh:mm"-string to HTML5 microformat duration

Tags: php, datetime, microdata, iso8601, dateinterval

I'm trying to convert a string of the format "HH:MM" (for example, 01:25 - 1 hour and 25 minutes), for usage as microdata in a recipe page.

I can create a `DateTime` object from the string like so:

```
$time = date_create_from_format("H:i", get_field("tilberedningstid"));
```

But how do I convert this `DateTime` object to a legit ISO8601 duration format?

I feel like I've tried everything. I played around with the `DateInterval` class, which should output (I think?) the right format, which would be `PT1H25M`, but I can't seem to convert my `DateTime` object to a format, that `DateInterval` can interpret. I've already tried `$interval = DateInterval($time->format(DateTime::ISO8601));`, which should be supported by the [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) class.

So the questions is simple: How do I convert a string "01:25" (HH:MM) to an ISO8601-string `PT1H25M` for usage in microformat, in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using the date interval? You can just use format. But because the PTHM chars are also valid codes, you must escape them.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('01:25');
echo $date->format('\P\TG\Hi\M');
//output: PT1H25M
?>
```

See [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for valid codes and [DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for how to use them

Comment: Of course, how silly of me. I guess I was mislead by the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) - thanks :) This works like a charm!